# Why is 0128 in octal considered not valid to convert in decimal?

Tags: decimal, bit, literals, octal

I'm practicing for an exam and I'm doing literals, what came up to me was a question that asked to convert 0128 octal into a decimal , so I also have the solution for this question which is that it has too many bits to be considered an octal so it can't be converted into a decimal as well, but the motivation of it is not described.

Do you know why because I'm trying to figure it out, but I couldn't find any answer yet.

Comment: 0128 is not a valid octal number. Octal can only have numbers from 0 to 7, so the 8 at the end makes it invalid, so we can't even consider it an octal number.

Comment: @Alejandro so it has nothing to do with the decimal converted, is only about the octal value itself?

Comment: Per the question you don't have a decimal to convert, you have an octal value (0128). But that value cannot represent an octal number, as the digit "8" isn't allowed in octal. From that on, the question no longer makes sense, and that's the only possible answer you can give.

Answer (score 1):

One answer is "invalid input" but a different answer might be to consider the input as "012" with the first non-octal character acting as the termination of the octal number.  The answer would therefore be 10 decimal.